# Detect change in a variable?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Is it possible to detect change in a variable?

I have the following:

`@Input('name') name: string;`

I would like to call a function whenever change is happened in this variable 'name'.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8):

You can do it the following:

```
private _name = '';

@Input('name')
set name(name: string) {
   this._name = name;
   doSomeStuff();
}

get name(): string { return this._name; }
```

Answer (score 3):

I am solve this question using default Angular feature named OnChanges, very similar to OnInit.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61720541/13514355

Comment: This is in fact the correct answer. Now sure why it was voted down!

Direct link to Angular document: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Comment: Further to my comment above, I implemented this mechanism and realized that `OnChanges` is not triggered if change is made outside of the views. A good explanation is here:

https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/ngonchanges-only-runs-when-the-input-change-comes-from-a-template-binding-like-component-8797b759ba0b

From this point of view, I would say the get / set solution in blog above or by @Mathias is better, but I don't like the use of private variable.