# Variable Change Detection - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm fairly new to Angular, I work mainly with VueJS. I want to know how I can detect when a variable gets updated. I'm updating my variable through a DataService. I read about `ngOnChanges()` but I saw that this only works for inputs.

This is pretty much my code:

```
import { DataService } from "../../service/my.service";

export class MainPage {
  myVar: String = ""; // this is the variable I want to listen when a change is made

   constructor (
    private data: DataService
   ) {}

   ngOnInit() {
    this.data.changeVar.subscribe(message => this.myVar = message);
  }
}
```

my.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
  changeVar = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMyVar (message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

This is where I'm updating the variable.

```
import { DataService } from "../../service/my.service";

export class AnotherPage {
  anotherVar: String = '';

  constructor(
    private data: DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.changeVar.subscribe(message => this.anotherVar = message)
  }

  myFunction () {
    this.data.changeMyVar("Hello"); // update variable to "Hello"
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Since you assign a new value to `myVar` in the Observable callback, you know when it changes. What other information do you want to get?

Comment: I want to run a function in MainPage when the value of the variable has been changed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `myVar` is changed only in the Observable callback defined in `ngOnInit`, you can call a method after changing the variable:

```
export class MainPage {

    myVar: string = "";

    ngOnInit() {
        this.data.changeVar.subscribe(message => {
            if (message !== this.myVar) {
                this.myVar = message;
                this.doSomething();
            }
        });
    }

    private doSomething() {
        ...
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if `myVar` can be changed in other places (since it is public), you can access it in a getter/setter, and call the method in the setter:

```
export class MainPage {

    private _myVar: string = "";

    get myVar(): string {
        return this._myVar;
    }
    set myVar(value: string) {
        if (value !== this._myVar) {
            this._myVar = value;
            this.doSomething();
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.data.changeVar.subscribe(message => this.myVar = message);
    }

    private doSomething() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your example helped a lot! :)

Comment: Im trying to use your solution, but I get "Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type". When I do message: any still does not work. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: I think that something like `subscribe((message: string) => ...` would eliminate the error message (assuming that `message` is a string).

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this:
https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

and get the object changes with:
changes.objectName

more details on the angular.io page.

Comment: 1. Its recommended adding solution as part of your answer along with any external link. 2. Please refer to this for better presenting your question/answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/3519504