# Detecting change within a variable's value or name

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I was looking through some questions and stumbled upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40077714/detect-change-in-a-variable). While this question was for Angular JS, I thought that it could be interesting for Python. Detecting every time that a variable's value changes could be very useful for debugging and seeing where a value got skewed along the way.

So my question is, can you find every time that a variable changes its value? Or name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to avoid parenthesis for getters/setters (`setvariable(5)`), the next best thing would be creating a property. You could then put any sort of debugging logic inside.

```py
class Container:

    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 5

    @property
    def value(self):
        print("Accessing value")
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, new_value):
        print(f"Setting value to {new_value}")
        self._value = new_value
```

Although it only works within a class. Besides this, I am not sure there is an easy way to accomplish what you desire. You can then set/get the variables:

```py
>>> x.value
Accessing value
5
>>> x.value = 10
Setting value to 10
```